# dlib 中心点を中心にカメラを回転させたいが上手くできない原因が知りたい。

Tags: c++

rotate_x();関数ですがなぜ上手く回転できないのでしょうか？　実行時の初期の状態では上下に中心点を中心に移動してくれるのですが左右に動かしたrotate();あと上下にキーを押すと斜めに回る？ようになってしまい上手く動作しません。参考サイトの回転式のX軸の一番上の式を使い実装しました。

参考サイト: http://www.f.waseda.jp/moriya/PUBLIC_HTML/education/classes/infomath6/applet/fractal/coord/

````
#include "Game.hpp"
#include "Input.hpp"
#include "Frame.hpp"



Game::Game()
{

    SetUseLighting(true);   

    SetUseZBuffer3D(true);
    SetWriteZBuffer3D(true);

    /*手前*/
    Vertex[0].pos = VGet(-RANGE, RANGE, 10);
    Vertex[0].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Vertex[0].dif =   color_dif;
    Vertex[0].spc =   color_spc;
    Vertex[0].u = 0.0f;
    Vertex[0].v = 0.0f;
    Vertex[0].su = 0.0f;
    Vertex[0].sv = 0.0f;

    Vertex[1].pos = VGet(RANGE, RANGE, 10);
    Vertex[1].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Vertex[1].dif = color_dif;
    Vertex[1].spc =   color_spc;
    Vertex[1].u = 1.0f;
    Vertex[1].v = 0.0f;
    Vertex[1].su = 0.0f;
    Vertex[1].sv = 0.0f;

    Vertex[2].pos = VGet(-RANGE, -RANGE, 10);
    Vertex[2].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Vertex[2].dif = color_dif;
    Vertex[2].spc = color_spc;
    Vertex[2].u = 0.0f;
    Vertex[2].v = 1.0f;
    Vertex[2].su = 0.0f;
    Vertex[2].sv = 0.0f;

    Vertex[3].pos = VGet(RANGE, -RANGE, 10);
    Vertex[3].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Vertex[3].dif = color_dif;
    Vertex[3].spc = color_spc;
    Vertex[3].u = 1.0f;
    Vertex[3].v = 1.0f;
    Vertex[3].su = 0.0f;
    Vertex[3].sv = 0.0f;

    /*奥*/
    Vertex[4].pos = VGet(-RANGE, RANGE, 10 + RANGE);
    Vertex[4].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Vertex[4].dif = color_dif;
    Vertex[4].spc =   color_spc;
    Vertex[4].u = 0.0f;
    Vertex[4].v = 0.0f;
    Vertex[4].su = 0.0f;
    Vertex[4].sv = 0.0f;

    Vertex[5].pos = VGet(RANGE, RANGE, 10 + RANGE);
    Vertex[5].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Vertex[5].dif = color_dif;
    Vertex[5].spc =   color_spc;
    Vertex[5].u = 1.0f;
    Vertex[5].v = 0.0f;
    Vertex[5].su = 0.0f;
    Vertex[5].sv = 0.0f;

    Vertex[6].pos = VGet(-RANGE, -RANGE, 10 + RANGE);
    Vertex[6].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Vertex[6].dif = color_dif;
    Vertex[6].spc =   color_spc;
    Vertex[6].u = 0.0f;
    Vertex[6].v = 1.0f;
    Vertex[6].su = 0.0f;
    Vertex[6].sv = 0.0f;

    Vertex[7].pos = VGet(RANGE, -RANGE, 10 + RANGE);
    Vertex[7].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Vertex[7].dif = color_dif;
    Vertex[7].spc =   color_spc;
    Vertex[7].u = 1.0f;
    Vertex[7].v = 1.0f;
    Vertex[7].su = 0.0f;
    Vertex[7].sv = 0.0f;
#define GROUND_Z 200
#define GROUND_X 200

    /*地面　ポリゴン*/
    Ground_Vertex[0].pos = VGet( -RANGE * GROUND_X, -RANGE * 2, RANGE * GROUND_Z);
    Ground_Vertex[0].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Ground_Vertex[0].dif = color_dif;
    Ground_Vertex[0].spc = color_spc;
    Ground_Vertex[0].u = 0.0f;
    Ground_Vertex[0].v = 0.0f;

    Ground_Vertex[1].pos = VGet(RANGE * GROUND_X, -RANGE * 2, RANGE * GROUND_Z);
    Ground_Vertex[1].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Ground_Vertex[1].dif = color_dif;
    Ground_Vertex[1].spc = color_spc;
    Ground_Vertex[1].u = 1.0f;
    Ground_Vertex[1].v = 0.0f;

    Ground_Vertex[2].pos = VGet(-RANGE * GROUND_X, -RANGE * 2, GROUND_Z * -RANGE);
    Ground_Vertex[2].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Ground_Vertex[2].dif = color_dif;
    Ground_Vertex[2].spc = color_spc;
    Ground_Vertex[2].u = 0.0f;
    Ground_Vertex[2].v = 1.0f;

    Ground_Vertex[3].pos = VGet(RANGE * GROUND_X, -RANGE * 2, GROUND_Z * -RANGE);
    Ground_Vertex[3].norm = VGet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Ground_Vertex[3].dif = color_dif;
    Ground_Vertex[3].spc = color_spc;
    Ground_Vertex[3].u = 1.0f;
    Ground_Vertex[3].v = 1.0f;

    /*地面インデックス*/
    Ground_Index[0] = 0;
    Ground_Index[1] = 1;
    Ground_Index[2] = 2;

    Ground_Index[3] = 1;
    Ground_Index[4] = 2;
    Ground_Index[5] = 3;



    /*手前*/
    Index[0][0] = 0;
    Index[0][1] = 1;
    Index[0][2] = 2;

    Index[0][3] = 1;
    Index[0][4] = 2;
    Index[0][5] = 3;

    /*奥*/
    Index[1][0] = 4;
    Index[1][1] = 5;
    Index[1][2] = 6;

    Index[1][3] = 6;
    Index[1][4] = 5;
    Index[1][5] = 7;

    /*左*/
    Index[2][0] = 0;
    Index[2][1] = 4;
    Index[2][2] = 2;

    Index[2][3] = 4;
    Index[2][4] = 2;
    Index[2][5] = 6;


    /*右*/
    Index[3][0] = 1;
    Index[3][1] = 5;
    Index[3][2] = 7;

    Index[3][3] = 1;
    Index[3][4] = 3;
    Index[3][5] = 7;




    /*上*/
    Index[4][0] = 0;
    Index[4][1] = 4;
    Index[4][2] = 5;

    Index[4][3] = 0;
    Index[4][4] = 1;
    Index[4][5] = 5;


    /*下*/
    Index[5][0] = 6;
    Index[5][1] = 7;
    Index[5][2] = 2;

    Index[5][3] = 3;
    Index[5][4] = 7;
    Index[5][5] = 2;


}


/* (x,y)の点を(mx,my)を中心にang角回転する */
void rotate(float* x, float* y, const float ang, const float mx, const float my)
{

    const float ox = *x - mx, oy = *y - my;
    *x = (ox * cos(ang)) + (oy * sin(ang));
    *y = (-ox * sin(ang)) + (oy * cos(ang));

    *x += mx;
    *y += my;


}

/*X軸回転*/
void rotate_X(float *y,float *z,const float ang,const float my,const float mz)
{
    const float oy = *y - my;
    const float oz = *z - mz;

    *y = (oy * cos(ang)) + (oz * sin(ang));
    *z = (-oy * sin(ang)) + (oz * cos(ang));

    *y += my;
    *z += mz;   


}

void Game::Update()
{
    /*カメラ回転*/
    if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_LEFT) > 0)
    {
        rotate(&cameraX, &cameraZ, +ROTATE_SPEED, targetX, targetZ);
    }
    else if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_RIGHT) > 0)
    {
        rotate(&cameraX, &cameraZ, -ROTATE_SPEED, targetX, targetZ);
    }
    else if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_UP) > 0)
    {
        rotate_X(&cameraY, &cameraZ, -ROTATE_SPEED, targetY, targetZ);
    }
    else if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_DOWN) > 0)
    {
        rotate_X(&cameraY, &cameraZ, +ROTATE_SPEED, targetY, targetZ);
    }
    if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_W) > 0)
    {

    }
    else if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_S) > 0)
    {

    }


    /*色　変更*/
    if(Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_SPACE) == 1)
    {
        ModeChange = !ModeChange;
    }
    /* false spcカラーを変更*/
    if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_Z) > 0 && ModeChange == false)
    {
        color_spc.r += -1;
        color_spc.g += -1;
        color_spc.b += -1;

    }
    else if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_X) > 0 && ModeChange == false)
    {
        color_spc.r +=  1;
        color_spc.g +=  1;
        color_spc.b +=  1;

        /*true difカラー変更*/
    }else if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_Z) > 0 && ModeChange == true)
    {
        color_dif.r += -1;
        color_dif.g += -1;
        color_dif.b += -1;

    }
    else if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_X) > 0 && ModeChange == true)
    {
        color_dif.r += 1;
        color_dif.g += 1;
        color_dif.b += 1;

    }

    if (Input::keyboard(KEY_INPUT_F1) == 1)
    {
        TextureMode = !TextureMode;
    }


    const int num = 4;





}
VECTOR v;



//45,48

void Game::DrawUpdate()
{
    SetCameraPositionAndTarget_UpVecY(VGet(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ), VGet(targetX, targetY, targetZ));



    for(int i = 0; i< 8; i++)
    {
        Vertex[i].dif = color_dif;
        Vertex[i].spc = color_spc;

    }



    int handle = LoadGraph("assets/resource/texturePos.png",false);

    for(int i =0 ;i < 6; i++){

        switch( i )
        {
            case 0:
            {
                Vertex[ 0 ].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[ 0 ].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[ 1 ].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[ 1 ].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[ 2 ].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[ 2 ].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[ 3 ].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[ 3 ].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[ 4 ].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[ 4 ].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[ 5 ].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[ 5 ].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[ 6 ].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[ 6 ].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[ 7 ].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[ 7 ].v = 0.0f;
            }
            break;


            case 1:
            {               
                Vertex[0].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[0].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[1].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[1].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[2].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[2].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[3].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[3].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[4].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[4].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[5].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[5].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[6].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[6].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[7].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[7].v = 1.0f;

            }
            break;


            case 2:
            {

                Vertex[0].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[0].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[1].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[1].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[2].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[2].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[3].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[3].v = 0.0f;



                Vertex[4].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[4].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[5].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[5].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[6].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[6].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[7].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[7].v = 1.0f;

            }
            break;

            /*右*/
            case 3:
            {

                Vertex[0].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[0].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[1].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[1].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[2].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[2].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[3].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[3].v = 1.0f;



                Vertex[4].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[4].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[5].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[5].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[6].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[6].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[7].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[7].v = 1.0f;

            }
            break;


            /*上*/
            case 4:
            {

                Vertex[0].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[0].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[1].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[1].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[4].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[4].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[5].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[5].v = 1.0f;

            }
            break;


            /*下*/
            case 5:
            {

                Vertex[2].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[2].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[3].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[3].v = 1.0f;

                Vertex[6].u = 0.0f;
                Vertex[6].v = 0.0f;

                Vertex[7].u = 1.0f;
                Vertex[7].v = 0.0f;
            }
            break;
        }
        if(TextureMode == true){
            DrawPolygonIndexed3D(Vertex, 8, Index[i], 2, handle, false);
        }else{
            DrawPolygonIndexed3D(Vertex, 8, Index[i], 2, DX_NONE_GRAPH, false);
        }
    }

    DrawPolygonIndexed3D(Ground_Vertex,4,Ground_Index,6,handle,false);

//  cameraY += -1;


    DrawFormatString(0, 0, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "カメラ座標　x: %.2f , y: %.2f , z:%.2f ", cameraX,cameraY,cameraZ);
//  DrawFormatString(0, 40, Get  color;(255, 255, 255), " test x: %.2f z: %.2f", xx, zz);

    if(ModeChange == false){
        DrawFormatString(0, 32 * 5, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "Mode: spc ");

        DrawFormatString(0, 32 * 1, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "color_spc.r: %d", color_spc.r);
        DrawFormatString(0, 32 * 2, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "color_spc.g: %d", color_spc.g);
        DrawFormatString(0, 32 * 3, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "color_spc.b: %d", color_spc.b);
    }else
    {
        DrawFormatString(0, 32 * 5, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "Mode: dif ");

        DrawFormatString(0, 32 * 1, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "color_dif.r: %d", color_dif.r);
        DrawFormatString(0, 32 * 2, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "color_dif.g: %d", color_dif.g);
        DrawFormatString(0, 32 * 3, GetColor(255, 255, 255), "color_dif.b: %d", color_dif.b);

    }


} ```
````

Comment: `rotate()` 関数は Y 軸を回転させていますよね。そのため、ユーザの視点(viewpoint)から見ると Z 軸が「傾く」事になります。傾いたままのZ 軸を回転させているので「斜めに回る」様に見えているのだと思います。

Comment: 質問ですがではどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: Y 軸の回転を元に戻せばよいかと(Z軸を「直立させる」)思うのですが、「左右に動かす」というのは平行移動とは違うのでしょうか？

Comment: 欲を言うとカメラをいろんな方向に回転させたいのですがこの場合どうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 実際に実行してはないのですが、カメラをターゲットとの距離を一体に保ったまま上下左右に公転させたい、その時「上下左右」は視点基準で行いたい、と言うことであっていますか？

Comment: そうですね、モン〇ンであるよなカメラをぐるっと回すやつをプログラムしたいのですが..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

カメラ位置は水平、鉛直方向の二つの角度として保存して、カメラ位置が必要になるたびにx,y,zに変換する方が楽だと思います。

参考: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%90%83%E9%9D%A2%E5%BA%A7%E6%A8%99%E7%B3%BB

Comment: 質問ですがクォータニオンはどうなのでしょうか？

Comment: 四元数は任意の軸周りの回転に使えるので、視点ベクトルと鉛直ベクトルに垂直なベクトル（外積で出る）周りに回転させることができますね。行列表現でも指定軸周りの回転は可能です　（https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9E%E8%BB%A2%E8%A1%8C%E5%88%97#%E4%BB%BB%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AE%E8%BB%B8%E5%91%A8%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E8%BB%A2 私は式を記憶していないので正しいかはわからないです）　複数のターゲットを切り替えながら移動していくのならばx,y,zで保持した方が良いかも知れませんが、単一のターゲットの周囲を回りたいだけならば極座標で十分だし簡単だろうと思った次第です

Comment: 質問ですが、http://marupeke296.com/DXG_No10_Quaternion.html　サイトの③の　Q = (cos(θ/2); xv・sin(θ/2), yv・sin(θ/2), zv・sin(θ/2))
R = (cos(θ/2); -xv・sin(θ/2), -yv・sin(θ/2), -zv・sin(θ/2))　数式の xv ・ sin(θ /2)の場所の・ってドット積だと思うのですがベクトルじゃないのでこれはなんの計算でしょうか？掛け算とかでしょうか？

Comment: 単なるスカラー同士の積です

Comment: 当初の質問から外れてきているので別質問でお願いします